# Displaying custom message on media library

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm trying to display custom error message in media library in WordPress, when the condition does meet error message is displayed with custom message that includes link but when I insert anchor tag in error message its displaying as plain text rather then HTML anchor tag.

```
add_filter('wp_handle_upload_prefilter','mdu_validate_image_size');
function mdu_validate_image_size( $file ) {
    $limit = 500;

$first_message = "click on link for the error information <a href='https://example.com' target='_blank'>Click here for more information</a>";

    // Define an array of allowed HTML tags
    $allowed_tags = array(
      'a' => array(
          'href' => array(),
          'target' => array(),
      ),
      'br' => array(),
      'p' => array(),
    );

$is_image = strpos($file['type'], 'image');

if ( ( $image_size > $limit ) && ($is_image !== false) ) {
    
    $file['error'] = wp_kses($first_message, $allowed_tags);
    return $file;
}

else
    return $file;
}
```

this is on going code, my main focus is to get anchor tag click on error message
As you can see that in error message its displaying as plain text.
[image: error message for achor tag]

I want anchor tag to be clickable, how can I get clickable anchor tag in file error message

Comment: Most likely you will have to go and find the place where this error message gets written into the output, it looks like there is HTML escaping applied at that point (or the result gets explicitly treated as text.)

Comment: Change wp_kses to wp_kses_post - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_kses_post/

Comment: wp_kses_post doesnt work, i have tried many others wp_die($too_big, 'Image Upload Error');, htmlspecialchars(),wp_kses(),wp_kses_post() none these work, we have use $file[error] handle to display error message, its seems its using some HTML escaping for sanitalization as same error handler is use for other type of upload too